# access_denied AADSTS50105: The signed in user is not assigned to a role for the application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Created applications in azure AD. I made the authorization using the "oauth2" protocol. It is necessary to make that other users (not the my`s organization), could be authorized using my applications. When I try to connect from another profile (personal account), I get this error:

```
access_denied AADSTS50105: The signed in user is not assigned to a role for the application
```

**multi-tenannted - on**

endpoint authorize = https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize

endpoint token = https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token

[setting app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oshEQ.png)

Answer (score 2):

> access_denied AADSTS50105: The signed in user is not assigned to a
>   role for the application

You could assign the related role to the user in the **Enterprise Applications** as a [global admin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles) in the tenant. 
[image]